# C#, limiting maximum input length in DatagridView DataGridCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

i am new to C# and currently working on a datagrid view which got 3 columns , I am dynamically creating rows by reading a config file . My need is to limit the number of inputs in each column. Maximum input length will change for each . Say Row 1 , column 3 have 6 as max length , Row 2 , column 3 have 12 as max length. I tried to cast this dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2] to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn but getting casting exception . I cannot set max input length through designer because the requirement is make it dynamically .

Please help

Thanks
Nibin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the RowDataBound or page load

For DataGrid

```
protected void dgv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("ControlName")).MaxLength = 6;
}
```

For GridView

```
((TextBox)gridview1.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("ControlName")).MaxLength = 6;
```

or

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{            
    ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ControlName")).MaxLength = 6;
}
```

Comment: Careful with NullReferenceExceptions, if it is loaded dinamically there is no guarantee the TextBox will exist :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].MaxInputLength = x;
```

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcell(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can access the MaxInputLength for a text box column like below:

```
private void SetTextBoxColumnLength(int index, int length) {
  if ( (dataGridView1.Columns.Count > index) && (length > 0) ) {
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn targetColumn = (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[index];
    targetColumn.MaxInputLength = length;
  }
}
```